# Without getting hit and being hit

Tags: common-word

I will try to cross the street without ***getting*** **hit** or ***being*** **hit** by a car

Which one is more common?

Answer (score 4):

Per [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=getting%20hit%20by%20a%20car%2C%20being%20hit%20by%20a%20car&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgetting%20hit%20by%20a%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeing%20hit%20by%20a%20car%3B%2Cc0), the more common *in print* (of the books they've recorded) is ***being*** *hit by a car*:

[image: hit by a car]

Note that this could be different with spoken English. Also, even if one phrase is more common than the other, they are both grammatical.

Comment: +1  But my feeling is that it is likely different in everyday conversation.  I know I’d say “without getting hit”.  *Getting* also implies a little bit more responsibility than does *being*

Comment: Try it with American English and British English filters.

Comment: @Jim That's obviously because *get* seems to imply intransitivity ("You let yourself be hit") while *being* is patently transitive ("They hit you"), which is not quite true always.

Answer (score 1):

Why are the two answers so far on the opposite sides?

**1** In general, *get* is far more common in AmE than in BrE.

**2 [Usage:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get)**

> The verb get is in the top five of the most common verbs in the English language. Nevertheless, there is still a feeling that almost any use containing get is somewhat informal. No general informal label has been applied to this dictionary entry, but in formal writing it is worth bearing this reservation in mind

Answer (score 0):

As a native English speaker, I would say “getting hit” is the more common of the two, at least in spoken English. In fact, “being hit” sounds a bit clunky to me, and I think I’ve ever heard someone say it that way.

Comment: Actually, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+hit%2Cgetting+hit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008) disagrees with you.  (Of course, it is based on written English.)

Comment: That's odd, as a native English speaker I have the opposite reaction. However I am rather old and British, perhaps one or both of those circumstances explains the difference.

Comment: Ah, I see! I’m young and American. That might be it.